# get ImageView src programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview

How to get `ImageView` src programmatically and set it in another `ImageView`

```
Drawable drawable = imageViewA....?
imageViewB.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Drawable drawable = imageViewA.getDrawable();
if(drawable != null){
    imageViewB.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **setImageResource(int)**

**imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_image);**

Comment: tnx, but that doesnt answer how to get the drawable

Answer (score 2):

Instead of get drawable you do...

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

and set to new image

```
newImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: why is it better than set the drawable?

Comment: nothing like better and also i used same thing that get drawable first and then convert it into bitmap and set it